# Is it necessary to get template ref dynamically?

Tags: angular

I declare a summary template in Base component. In form component, I have four tabs, when user clicks the last tab, I render the summary template. Is it necessary to get summary template ref **only when user click the last tab**? Any advantages?

**In Base component**

```
  <ng-template #appSummary let-summary>xx</ng-template>
  getAppSummaryRef(): TemplateRef<any> {
    return this.appSummary ;
  }
```

**In form component**

```
constructor(){
  this.lastTab$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((summaryTab: any) => {
      this.summaryRef = !!summaryTab ? this.baseComp.getAppSummaryRef() : null;
    });
}
```

***Or just***

```
constructor(){
  this.summaryRef = this.baseComp.getAppSummaryRef();
}
```

Comment: afaik you can pass the reference as soon as it has been read from the template, so it should be possible in the afterViewInit hook.